# How to bind names on images on a data list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've a data list in which images are getting binded dynamically from database.
The name is also coming but its displaying separately, means above the image but
my requirement is to display it on the image.
How can I bind the name on the image itself when mouse hover.
Please help

Thanks in advance...!!!

```
<div class="marquee" id="mycrawler2">
                        <asp:DataList ID="FetchPhotos" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
                  <ItemTemplate>

                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td ><a href="MemberProfileDisplay.aspx?MemberId=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem ,"MemberId") %>" target="_blank" class="edit" "><img src="images/profilephotos/small/<%# Eval("SmallProfilePhoto")%>" width="185" height="240"/></a></td> </tr></table>
                  <asp:label ID="lbltitle" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:label>
                  </ItemTemplate></asp:DataList></div>
```

Code Behind

```
FetchPhotos.DataSource = Photos;
FetchPhotos.DataBind();
```

In this code I'm binding name and image both to data list.
my requirement is to display it on the image.

Comment: Show us some code. I'd probably try going with absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: Please provide more details, a jsfiddle or code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing 
`img src='images/profilephotos/small/<%# Eval("SmallProfilePhoto")%>' width="185" height="240"`
with
`asp:Image ID="imgSth" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/profilephotos/small/<%# Eval("SmallProfilePhoto")%>" ToolTip='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'
width="185" height="240"`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really blunt example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
                        onmouseover="document.getElementById('1.png').style.visibility ='visible';"
                        onmouseout="document.getElementById('1.png').style.visibility ='hidden';"
                    />
                    <a id="1.png" href="user1" style="visibility: hidden; position: relative; right: 50%;">User #1</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```